# Is there an Excel function to check if value is in a set of values?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Assume we have values in column `A`, defining a target set:

```
  |  A   |
----------
1 | 15-X |
2 | 31-T |
3 | 28-H |
```

And there's a another column `D`, containing values which should be checked by criteria "belongs to the target set". The expected result is shown in column `E`.

```
  |  D   |    E
-----------------
1 | 15-X |   Yes
2 | 12R4 |   No 
3 | K45Y |   No
4 | 28-H |   Yes
5 | 3WWT |   No
6 | K45Y |   No
```

Could you help me to construct a function to use in the column `E`?
It would be perfect if it's solvable in terms of standard functions.

I look for something like

```
=THE_FUNC( <value_to_check> , A1:A3 )
```

**UPDATE**

I've come to a solution, which is too wordy, but let me put it here:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,D1:D1,1))), "Yes", "No")
```

Comment: Another fast option would be to use `MATCH`, you should at least know about the existence of it for future reference.

Comment: @JvdV, that's exactly what I was looking for. Please post it as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIF()

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,D1),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 1):

So as per my comment:

[image]

The formula used in `E2`:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(D2,A:A,0)),"No","Yes")
```

Drag down...